# Sending an array as a parameter to a component inline

Tags: c#, blazor

Is it possible to send a initialized array inline to a blazer component?

I have a paramater in a component

```
[Parameter]
public List<string> ListItems { get; set; } = new List<string> { "One", "Two" };
```

I would like to be able to send an the array values when I create the component

```
<ShowListComponent HeadingText="Shoping List"  ListItems="new List<string> { "three", "four" }"/>
```

This doesn't seam to work i am getting a `malformed ShowListComponent` error

I am currently running preview 9 i just updated it five minutes ago to be sure i was on the newest version.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Create new variable for every component to pass is really painful.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is add parenthesis (brackets) around the new inline list, your new code should look like this...

```
<ShowListComponent HeadingText="Shoping List"  ListItems="@(new List<string> { "three", "four" })"/>
```

Blazor sometimes struggles with special characters and the parenthesis help to distinguish what belongs to what.

Comment: I checked your code but didn't work, Error is ") expected" at {

Comment: @Ali.P the code does work, I've been doing this in Blazor for nearly 2 years and works every time. Try again.

Comment: Why it's unvoted, this should work, as long as the array not changed

Answer (score 0):

```
<ShowListComponent HeadingText="Shoping List"  ListItems="@ListItems"/>

@code {

private List<string> ListItems=new List<string> { "three", "four" }

}
```

Parameter in the component:

```
[ParamArray]
public List<string> ListItems { get; set; } = new List<string> { "One", "Two" };
```